# Creating a SharePoint app from a custom solution(.wsp)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, office365

So I have this solution with list workflows created in SharePoint Designer and I want it to be published in SharePoint store. I don't know how to package it with .app extension. Is it possible or not? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around to generate an .app file from SharePoint Designer. You have to copy the workflows into your SharePoint App solution of visual studio and after that generate package of the solution so that you will get .app file.

Now you need to add that .app file to your approved **Seller Dashboard Account** of Microsoft. When that app is submitted, it will take around 24 hours to verify by Microsoft team. Once verified the app will be live on SharePoint store.

Read carefully [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220033(v=office.15).aspx) post.